# Conjugacy class of upper triangular matrices over algebraically closed field: Reference request

Tags: matrices, ra.rings-and-algebras, conjugacy-classes

We know that the conjugacy classes of $A\in M_n(\mathbb{C})$ are determined by the characteristic polynomial of  $A$ and a partition of $n$. Is there an analogous statement for upper triangular matrices? Since over an algebraically closed field a matrix $A$ is always triangularisable, I am hoping similar statements are true for upper triangular matrices.

But I am unable to find any reference for the same. If anyone knows any reference about the same, please let me know about it. Any help regarding this will be appreciated.

Comment: It's not exactly what you describe. The characteristic polynomial determines a partition $n=\sum_{t\in\mathbf{C}} n_t$ and then the Jordan form determines a partition of each $n_t$.

Comment: In any case, $E_{12}$ and $E_{23}$ are not conjugate by invertible upper triangular matrices.

Comment: That's a great example. Thank you. Do you have any reference for the conjugacy classes of upper triangular matrices?

Comment: Over finite fields, the analogous problem is notoriously difficult.

Comment: @GeoffRobinson I read about it some days ago, looks like there are long standing open problems about it. Just curious to know, if all the diagonal entries are different, i.e. the regular semisimple case, do these matrices contribute to single conjugacy class?

Comment: I interpreted the last question differently: If the diagonal entries of $U$ and $V$ are equal to each other IN THE SAME ORDER, and are all distinct, are $U$ and $V$ conjugate? The answer is yes. Proof: We can assume that $V$ is diagonal. Let $(i,j)$ be the position with $U_{ij} \neq 0$ and $j-i$ minimal. Then, for an appropriate $t$, the matrix $(1+t E_{ij}) U (1+t E_{ij})^{-1}$ is $0$ in the $(i,j)$ position, and is still zero in all the places closer to the diagonal. (This computation uses that $U_{ii} \neq U_{jj}$. Continuing in this manner, we can make $U$ diagonal.)

Comment: That's awesome. Thank you @DavidESpeyer.

Comment: The main issue seems to be the case of nilpotent matrices.